# How to turn off VS Code Error "Property does not exist on type {}" (ts) on .JS files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am editing React JS files, not TS. The latest VS Code marks some tokens with an ellipsis (...) and displays the following:

[image]

This did not happen before, it started with the latest upgrade of VS Code. How to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

You can use casting to inforce typing for example:

```
interface IUser{
  firstName: string
  lastName:string
}
 
const hi = {} as IUser
hi.firstName // ok
```